# What is the difference between AWS EMRs "Elapsed Time" and Spark UI "Task Time"?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, spark-ui

On EMR I see that my job took 12 minutes to run - according to the `Elapsed Time` column. However, when I go to the `Spark UI > Executors` tab the `Task Time (GC Time)` shows 1 hr (4 s).
I totalled up the times as well i could from the Event Timeline and its aprrox 12 minutes.

1 - What does the `Task Time (GC Time)` mean? I also see in the `Spark UI > Jobs > Event Timeline` that the job took 12 minutes to run.
2 - Does this affect the total time for the job to run in any way?